# Windows 7: run graphicscard as it's run during safe-mode

Tags: windows-7, safe-mode

My graphics card seems to die - it produces a lot of horizontal lines of garbage so that it's actually difficult to see what's going on on the screen.

I'm pretty sure it's the graphics card being broken because:

- the mouse cursor is not affected by the graphics error (so it can't be a problem with the screen)
- ever since this is happening, the bios bootscreen shows some (different) errors too
- a 2nd Windows 7 installation on my computer shows exactly the same graphics errors.

The thing is, if I boot in safe mode, everything is fine (only a few areas of particular colors show something that looks a bit like dithering, but that doesn't disturb much).

I assume that's because in safe mode windows 7 renders in software mode or doesn't make use of some hardware shaders or whatever..

I'd like to know what I can do so that I can run my graphics card in normal mode the same way as it is run when booting into safe-mode?

Comment: Is this a desktop or laptop? If it's the former you should be able to set the BIOS to use the motherboards on-board graphics (presuming it has some) as first priority over a graphics card - although you'll then have to change where your screen is connected.

Answer (score 2):

If you uninstall the drivers for your video card, then Windows will use standard vesa/vga drivers.

This may be enough to keep the card running with minimal resources, and so not hit whatever is glitching.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the graphic card in device manager. It disables the drivers, forcing Windows to load the fail-safe VGA/VESA driver

Comment: How does this fix it?

Comment: It disables the drivers, forcing Windows to load the fail-safe VGA/VESA driver.